# How to mock react-native Platform.OS with Jest?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, mocking

Jest runner use "ios" as default OS (Plaform.OS) for react-native tests.
How to do test in jest that have platform dependent code. An further more, how to mock static constant imported in a module.

Here is the code:
utils.ts:

```
import { Platform } from "react-native";
export const isIOS = Platform.OS === "ios"; // note constant, not function
```

items.ts:

```
import { isIOS } from "@my/utils";
export const items = [{
    id: 1,
    name: isIOS ? "Apple" : "Android"
}]
```

test:

```
import { items } from "./items";

// not working because Platform.OS is used statically during import statement
it("should be android", () => {
  Platform.OS = "android"; // too late...
  expect(items[0].name).toBe("Android"); // fail: Apple
}

it("should be ios", () => {
  Platform.OS = "ios";
  expect(items[0].name).toBe("Apple"); // works due to default platform value in Jest
}
```

I saw some workaround using `jest.resetModules()` & `require` inside test/it block (and change Plaform.OS before require) but does exist a more simple way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2):

In your test file

```js
import { Platform } from 'react-native'

jest.doMock('react-native/Libraries/Utilities/Platform.android.js', () => ({
  OS: 'android',
  select: jest.fn(),
}))

jest.doMock('react-native/Libraries/Utilities/Platform.ios.js', () => ({
  OS: 'android',
  select: jest.fn(),
}))

describe('Platform', () => {
  it('Should be android', () => {
    expect(Platform.OS).toEqual('android')
  })

  it('Should be ios', () => {
    Platform.OS = 'ios'
    expect(Platform.OS).toEqual('ios')
  })

  it('Should be android', () => {
    Platform.OS = 'android'
    expect(Platform.OS).toEqual('android')
  })
})
```

Comment: How did you switch by test case ? Because imports are resolved before test run. If I mock Platform on top of test suite, I can only have 1 plaform at same time per test file.

Comment: Good question, I've updated my answer so you can see how to change the platform. Basically by mocking select function you can also mock Platform per specific test

Comment: utils.ts with `const isIOS = Platform.OS === "ios"` will not work. Because it's resolved a import time, not run test time. So modifying  Platform.OS inside a test will not work. Ex: `expect(isIOS).toBe(true)` will always return same value even If you change `Platform.OS` just before.

Comment: In this case probably it makes sense to split your tests into 2 test files: one for iOS and one for Android.

Comment: Also what could be done is to use ```jest.setup.js``` with env variables. Inside of ```jest.setup.js``` you mock ```Platform``` depending on what you pass with the env variables via ```process.argv```. And then you can run your test specifying the platform: ```yarn test <path-to-your-test> --platform=ios```. Does it work for you?

Comment: This require to launch tests twice and how to deal with platform specificities in tests suite ?

Comment: In your case the problem relates to how you've organized the code. 
Don't initialize code depending on the platform. Wrap it into functions. E.g., instead of using const `isIOS = Platform.OS === "ios"` use `const isIOS = () => Platform.OS === "ios"`. Instead of `items =...` use `const getItems = (platform) => ...`. 
Otherwise you will need to run your code twice.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replacing the iOS implementation with the Android implementation works. Use the other way around for Android.

```
    jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Utilities/Platform.ios.js', () => ({
      ...jest.requireActual(
        'react-native/Libraries/Utilities/Platform.android.js',
      ),
    }));
```